# how to get browser stored cookies using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, get

I have question regarding accessing all browser cookies using javascript, i was able to do this in shell script but i want to access the cookie information stored in local machine which needs to pass to server.

Regards

Comment: Shell script to access browser cookies? a Typo?

Answer (score 3):

You can access them using

```
document.cookies
```

Comment: ya tried this but it'll give me only the current page cookies, what i need all the browser cookies

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access *all* browser cookies. Only cookies set for the current domain and not marked 'http-only' (or 'secure' if you are on a non-SSL page).

In javascript use `document.cookies`

**Update**
The browser has built in functionality, as a security feature, to prevent you from reading cross domain cookies. As long as the javascript runs in the browser, there is no method to access those cookies, let alone execute a shell command. Google for: [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

What you basically are looking for has so many security/privacy implications, I don't even know where to start explaining the dangers.

Comment: I tried document.cookies as you told i got only current domain cookies but i need browser stored cookies. Is there any way to execute shell script or unix commands by javascript??

Comment: ok, if i use shell script i can't able to access the local machine cookie file. Am doing this to bypass the sites which asks subscription in php curl() function, do you have any better method to store all cookies of specific domain.

Comment: And even it is helpful if you can tell how to access the sqlite database from javascript

Answer (score 3):

Imagine that was possible. You browse to an arbitrary site that loads third-party ads, a rogue ad reads all your browser cookies and, voilá!, some guy from the Russian Mafia has the "Remember me" cookies and session IDs for all your sites. He can read your e-mail, see your pics on Facebook and retrieve money from your PayPal account.

Comment: Psst! He's the guy from the russian mafia!

Comment: That i agree but is there any other way to access all cookies of a specific site using javascript??

Answer (score 2):

```
function getCookie(name) {
  // Split cookie string and get all individual name=value pairs in an array
  var cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";");
  // Loop through the array elements
  for (var i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++) {
    var cookiePair = cookieArr[i].split("=");
    /* Removing whitespace at the beginning of the cookie name
        and compare it with the given string */
    if (name == cookiePair[0].trim()) {
      // Decode the cookie value and return
      return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
    }
  }
  // Return null if not found
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function listCookies() {
var theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
var aString = '';
for (var i = 1 ; i <= theCookies.length; i++) {
    aString += i + ' ' + theCookies[i-1] + "\n";
}
return aString;
}
```